# From visio block digrame to c++ code or text description

Tags: c#, c++, macros, ms-office, visio

I heard it is possible to generate c# code from visio Enterprise version. And I would like to ask if it is possible to achieve my aim simliar:

I have a txt file stating like:

```
module a
module b
a.port0 b.port0
a.port1 b.port1
```

I want to achieve

1. If I draw two block in VISIO, and use two line to connection the two blocks. If it is possible to generate a simliar txt file I listed above.
2. With the given txt file, if it is possible to let the visio draw the two blocks and connections?
3. If it is possible, what language I shall use to programme visio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python or Ruby, Perl would also suffice. They all are powerful in terms of text manipulation and file handling.